# Is it possible to use Polymer 2 for building browser extention?

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-2.x

By browser extension I mean WebExtension https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/Add-ons/WebExtensions.

I tried to use it for just local files and got:

> Access to Imported resource at 'file:///' from origin 'null' has been
>   blocked by CORS policy: Invalid response. Origin 'null' is therefore
>   not allowed access.

WebExtension (especially for popup of settings) don't have specific server.
Their links will be like chrome-extension://pkngljipephggpkgjfkjhggmcjfmhgkn/page.html

Comment: The answer is yes. Its a error you are receiving due to a different issue. CORS is cross origin request error. what were you doing when you got this exactly

Comment: Just HTML imports

Comment: Something going wrong in the way you are importing. Its not an error related to polymer. may be something in chrome is blocking. have you tried jquery or something else to test what is going wrong?

Comment: i saw few people asking here on stackoverflow when they were developing some browser extensions, so yes it is propably possible, but i don't know about any tutorials or articles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated answer after year of production**

I used Polymer 1 and Polymer 3. For both you need to create whole building ecosystem. In case of Polymer 3 it is very very difficult due to WRONG! documentation for `polymer-build` (don't read documentation, read source code directly)

---

Just tested and here is answer. Shortly: yes, but with complications.

After inserting only one Polymer element I got many errors:
Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". 
Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-AYzkEOy570v3pgwSjL36msfNQGIBNCoa6ppxJtI8Fag='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

In requirements to extension Chrome 31+ - so I cannot change content security policy. I cannot use inline `<script>` tags for any templates.

So I modified code of Polymer by moving all inline scripts to separate scripts and it's worked.

Cons: I cannot make automatic update of code if Polymer will be updated. Each time I need to rewrite it's code.

Answer (score 0):

Vulcanize and Crisper tools can be used to workaround the CORS/CSP issues.

Lot's of how-to details here: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/tools/optimize-for-production

Both tools have Gulp plugins, so you can script the build step like this:

```
gulp.task('vulcanize', function() {
  return gulp.src('index.html')
    .pipe(vulcanize({
      inlineScripts: true,
      inlineCss: true
    }))
    .pipe(crisper())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('popup'));
});
```